# what is other solution for "required" in null safety to get uid in firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, dart-null-safety, null-safety

I'm learning flutter from the older version with the new one. so, I have many times problem with null safety.

I have code in `database.dart` file like this :

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class DatabaseService {
  final String uid;
  DatabaseService({required this.uid});
}
```

it works and no error appeared when I add "required", but I can't use  `DatabaseService()` parameter in `home.dart` file :

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot?>.value(
      initialData: null,
      value: DatabaseService().brews,
      child: Scaffold(),
  }
}
```

the error in `home.dart` is

```
The named parameter 'uid' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.
Try adding the required argument.
```

and, if I don't add **required** in `DatabaseService({this.uid})` then the error will appear in `database.dart`

```
The parameter 'uid' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.
Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.
```

then how I can use `DatabaseService()` in other file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in nullsafety there is 2 type called non-null and nullable

- Non-null is where your variable cannot be empty so you got to assign value to it
- Nullable is where your variable can be empty, it able to run without any value (basically it doesn't require any value in it)

in your case you can try using this '?' symbol to make it nullable

just like this :

```
class DatabaseService {
  final String? uid;
  DatabaseService({this.uid});
}
```

and you don't need to put required in front of it, because it allowed to be empty

hope it helps!, sorry for my bad explanation

Comment: so, what is the difference between (?) <Question Mark> and (!) <Exclamation Mark> in null safety?

Comment: if you mean when you call nullable variable and you place (?) your statement has to be non mandatory, but if you can actually make sure that your nullable variable is free from null you can use the (!) because if you call it but its value is null, there will be error appear on your screen, basically the (!) mark is for make sure that your nullable variable contains value

Answer (score 1):

Use null safety operator if uid is not required

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class DatabaseService {
  final String? uid;
  DatabaseService({this.uid});
}
```